# keyboard not working properly

Tags: keyboard

I just installed ubuntu 13.10 on top of my windows7.
Every thing is working fine, but my keyword is acting weirdly, for example now:
When I press @ it out put "
and esc doesn't do anything and pressing | outputs >.

Joe

Answer (score 1):

You need to choose the correct keyboard layout, sounds like you have default USA instead of UK.

Comment: Always used to happen to me when installing XP back in the day.

Comment: @user3178791 If this answer solves your issue please take a minute and check the check mark under the vote count to the left, this will [signify to everyone](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) that your issue's been resolved.

Comment: Check it's ok again after rebooting. I have a problem with this, it seems to be a bug. If you still have the problem every time you reboot the only solution which has worked for me is to remove something called ibus.